# Custom Entities resolution is showing Null

Tags: botframework

I am trying to  fetch the Entity Values in the Luis response, but could not do that. i have tested same with pre built in entity types and it worked.

My question to LUIS is like below. 
Question : turn lights off in the kitchen.

I have configured below in LUIS application.

Intent : turn off
Custom Entity : room

Custom entity is labelled to kitchen.

When I sent the data to bot and  I am receiving the custom entity resolution value as null where  lUIS stores the entity Values like Kitchen

how could i get that  custom entity value in the response.

Comment: Thanks for joining Stack Overflow! Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Comment: updated. thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @chaitut It's more useful to add a small bit of code so people can see your specific situation. Otherwise, it's just a guess and you're unlikely to get an answer or your question will be closed.